# Time travel with tf - tutorial - confusing target and source frames

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding the time travel with tf tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf%20%28Python%29

It is stated:

> Give the transform from this frame, at this time ... to this frame, at this time. Specify the frame that does not change over time, in this case the "/world" frame, and the variable to store the result in.

But I find that confusing, since I thought it was:

> Give the transform TO this frame, at this time ... FROM this frame, at this time. Specify the frame that does not change over time, in this case the "/world" frame, and the variable to store the result in.

Did I miss something or is the order of TO/FROM wrong/misleading?

From what I can see [from the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#ac01a9f8709a828c427f1a5faa0ced42b) you pass the target first, then the source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296844/time-travel-with-tf---tutorial---confusing-target-and-source-frames/) by [Azergoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34694/azergoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right that it's a little confusing.

The transform from Frame A to Frame B is the transform which when applied to an object in frame B will represent it in frame A.

More info here: https://answers.ros.org/question/194046/the-problem-of-transformerlookuptransform/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2